# Error trying To use Microsoft lifeCam VX-3000

Tags: windows, webcam

I bought a Microsoft LifeCam VX-3000 web camera for may parent's Dell Dimension 3000 computer running XP SP 3, and I cannot get it to run.  THe installation ran successfully, but when I try to run it, I get the error:

Faulting application lifecam.exe, version 3.21.263.0, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 5.1.2600.5781, fault address 0x00012afb.

The microsoft help link really didn't help... how do I even resolve this type of error?

**EDIT**: The web cam appears to work, but their lifecam software seems to cause an error.  I can get the video/audio to work with Skype...

Comment: I just plugged in a vx-2000.  Similar situation - Microsoft's own software (latest version) can't see it,  but Skype can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the software still fails, but the software works with Skype, so it must be an error with the supporting software.  Oh well, at least it works with what I want it to...

Comment: I just plugged in a vx-2000 lifecam.  Skype detected it straight away, but microsoft's own software can't see it. Poor form.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the application, it could be a faulty dll file.

Comment: Did that, no luck.  Still getting the error...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using an up-to-date version of the software/driver.  Often the cd that comes with a device is already several versions old by the time you go to install it.  Here's a link with the most recent software for your camera:
http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/download/DownloadResult.aspx?category=ICE&type=LifeCam&name=68A-00001&os=XPSP2x64&lang=en

Comment: Get the message "A current version of Lifecam software is installed." and exits...  I added some additional info; seems like an issue with the LifeCam software, not the web cam... can get video/audio to work externally.